# concatenate multiple webm video in browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm a noob who's trying to concatenate multiple videos. My meteor webapp download multiple videos of 2s each via http. I would like to play theese videos one after another, without the user noticing they are separate videos.

Is it possible with html5 and JS?

Comment: no, even if you play all the videos in sequence, the user will notice that they are different videos. A tricky solution may be capturing all the frames, loading all your video into a canvas, then show all captured frames in sequence with custom controls. Why don't you do a straight server-side concatenation?

Comment: he will notice it even if they are the split of a same video?

Comment: this is a solution to load balance a live streaming. The source upload to the server, which load balance between multiple servers. So you get one stream from server A, one stream from server B, and the browser concatenate them.